# Python list of lists to one dimensional using comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What would be the syntax to convert this loop into one line comprehension operator?

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
]

all_records = []
for entry in lst:
    all_records.extend(entry)

#[1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 5, 2, 5, 10, 11]
```

When i am doing

```
all_records = [entry for entry in lst]
```

it gives

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3], [0, 1, 5], [2, 5, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might flatten 2D list using following comprehension

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
flat = [j for i in lst for j in i]
print(flat)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: There should be way to do it more efficiently without two `for` loops after all i managed to do without comprehension with just one loop.

Comment: @RomanToasov you didn't _write_ the second `for` loop, but `extend`'s [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is linear on the number of items you're adding.